# Who can configure endorsement policy in Hyper Ledger Fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am learning Hyper-ledger fabric and I would like to know more about how to configure Endorsement policies.

Answer (score 2):

Endorsement policies are configured at chaincode instantiation time, and they are configured as logical gate predicates in the following grammer rules:
`EXPR(E[, E...])`
while `EXPR` is `AND` or `OR` and `E` is either a principal (i.e Org1.Admin, Org1.Member) or a nested expression `EXPR(..)`

Example: `"AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"`

When you do `"peer instantiate chaincodeName"` you pass `-P policyString`
and the `policyString` is an expression such as above.

Example:
 `peer chaincode instantiate -C testchainid -n mycc -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P "AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"`

Comment: Who creates the channel, defines de endorsement policy. Then, it has repercussion in all the transactions.

Comment: Of course it has, but the one that instantiates the chaincode on the channel is an Admin of its organization, so it's safe.